# Multiple angular modules with same dependencies for karma testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I have a question.   I have multiple angular modules that have the same dependency need. Currently the code below works well for the application to run but not for testing...see below

`angular.module('app',['d1','d2'])
    angular.module('app.home', []);
    angular.module('app.about',[]);`

I am also doing karma testing so when I pass the 'app.about' module and karma is asking for the 'd1' dependency.  I then added 'app' module and it works but I will have to add 'd2' to my 'app.about' specs even though 'd2' has nothing to do with 'app.about'.

I then proceeded to do the below fixes:

    `angular.module('app',['d1','d2'])
    angular.module('app.home', ['d1']);
    angular.module('app.about',['d1']);`

It feels that is repetitive.   So my question is...is this how angular modules work? What if later I use 'd1' and 'd2' in all my modules?  Would this not make my modules repetitive? Again, I need the code below because of karma testing.

`angular.module('app',['d1','d2'])
    angular.module('app.home', ['d1','d2']);
    angular.module('app.about',['d1','d2']);`

Thanks for your help. P.S. I looked at johnpapa's guide but I did not seem to be clear on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix...i had a login service (in a 'login' module) that was injected in a controller (in the 'about' module) and the run block (in the 'app' module). I had to move the login service to the 'core' module of the application and it worked like a charm. The 'core' module had all 3rd party dependencies and core modules used through out the app. The 'app' module had the 'login', 'about' and 'core' modules. No need to mock up other services. :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to supply mock dependencies if those dependencies will affect the outcome of the tests. Often they won't. However, you can "remap" any dependency by simply registering your mock over the top of the actual implementation.

For example:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var serviceId = 'apiService';
    angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
        ['$q', apiService]);

    function apiService($q) {
        var service = {
            sendData: mockFunction,
            saveUserState: mockFunction
        }

        return service;


        function mockFunction(){return $q.when({})}

    }

})();
```

The down side is this mocked version will be used everywhere, but that is often what you want.

Note that if app.home and app.about don't contain implicit dependencies on things in d2, you should be able to avoid bootstrapping d2 by just initializing the module under test:

`beforeEach(module('app.home'));`

Comment: Sorry Amy,  I am not clear on you explanation.   Especially on the remapping and registering or dependencies.

Comment: So if you have a real service named 'apiService' and in your karma config you point to the above file, let's call it `apiServiceMock.js`, then any code that uses apiService will use apiServiceMock instead.

Comment: ok but the problem I am having is not with a service... it is with a module.  for example I have app module which has ui.router module as dependency and also app.about module which also depend on ui.router module.

When testing app.about module in karma, I am just including app.about module.  Since app.about module depends on ui.router, I am also including app module.   

The problem happens when app module gets included it also has other dependencies and karma gives me an error about missing providers.

Comment: The point is you could create an entirely alternative ui.router implementation by overriding all its components. But also you seem to have missed my point about "if you don't have any *implicit* dependencies between your modules..." You apparently do, so you need to clean up the separation between your modules. Otherwise, just bung everything in one module.

Comment: I found the fix...i had a login service (in a 'login' module)  that was injected in a controller (in the 'about' module) and the run block (in the 'app' module).  I had to move the login service to the 'core' module of the application and it worked like a charm. The 'core' module had all 3rd party dependencies and core modules used through out the app.  The 'app' module had the 'login', 'about' and 'core' modules. No need to mock up other services. :)

Comment: @btinoco I have the same problem you posted here but based on your last comment it seems to me that you have solved this with a different approach then the accepted answer. It would be great for me and for future readers if you add your own answer to this question. Thank you